# scalesPageToFit broken on UIWebView after keyboard is shown?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=768, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

And I am setting scalesPageToFit:

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

At first this works correctly. When I go from portrait to landscape it zooms in so the width of the device is always 768px. I can go back and forth with no issues (portrait <-> landscape).

As soon as I activate the virtual keyboard, whether it be through a contentEditable or text area, it stops working completely, even after I dismiss the keyboard.

Is this a bug in the UIWebView? Is there anything else I need to do to make this work? Is there a work-around I can use? The width, no matter the orientation, has to be 768px.

Comment: I confirmed that this is still a bug in iOS 7. The workaround is to catch the keyboard notifications and refresh the web view. A disgusting hack but all I have so far.

Comment: @phatmann You might be able to do what I suggested with method swizzling at runtime. I submitted a bug report back in Sep 2012, and have yet to get a reply. The answer is a little vague, and it has been a while, but should give you something to go on. Reloading the UIWebView for me wasn't an option. I'm now using a TextKit powered UITextView and dropped iOS 6 support.

Comment: Luke, thanks for the update. Based on your answer below, I am not quite sure which methods to swizzle and what the updated methods should do. Can you provide some more info? Also, do you think the swizzling would cause Apple to reject the app, since it would be accessing private methods?

Comment: @phatmann If they catch you. Runtime methods are harder to catch. Constant NSString @"" and selectors are scannable, so you'll likely have to build them differently (C string maybe?). I don't remember all the details, but it involves changing the internal scale. If you search for iOS 7 private headers you can see all the functions. class-dump can generate the headers too (get on brew). Set some breakpoints. _setDocumentScale is the place to start.

Comment: I submitted a Technical Suppport Incident to Apple this morning, complete with a sample app that clearly shows the errant behavior. I expect to hear back from them after Thanksgiving break.

The sample app showed me a few more things: (1) Reloading the page does not always fix the issue (2) The web view attempts to move all its contents (not just a text field) out of the way of the keyboard by scaling. This is apparently where the the bug originates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with Apple's private class UIDocumentView. For what ever reason `viewportConfigurationsDidChange` gets stuck on a zoom scale after the keyboard is activated, which is set by calling `_setDocumentScale`. When it's supposed to change to 1.333, for example, it gets stuck on 1.0.

It's "fixable" by writing a category for UIWebDocumentView, which is a subclass of UIDocumentView that doesn't implement these methods (so you can call the super's).

Despite my best efforts I couldn't find a way to fix this using the public API. I tried messing with the UIScrollView's zoom level, but I could never get that to work correctly. The content would get shifted, and other weird things would happen. Even tried doing it with JavaScript.

So the only way to fix it is through category on private classes.

**This would never be approved in the app store.**

So until Apple fixes this, SOL.

Answer (score 0):

*WARNING: this solution uses private APIs. Any app that uses this code might be rejected from the app store. I am posting it so people at least have a working solution.*

```
@interface UIWebDocumentView : UIView
- (void)_setDocumentScale:(float)scale;
@end

@interface UIWebView (DocumentView)
- (UIWebDocumentView *)_documentView;
@end

- (void)resetScale:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    UIWebDocumentView *webDocumentView = [webView _documentView];
    CGFloat contentWidth = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollWidth;"] floatValue];
    CGSize viewSize = webView.bounds.size;
    float scale = viewSize.width / contentWidth;
    [webDocumentView _setDocumentScale:scale];
}
```

Call `resetScale` after the bounds of the web view change.