# iPad - Zooms in on orientation change while focused on input field

Tags: ios, html, ipad

This is similar issue with [Focus on input field and orientation change messes up zoom level on iOS 6 Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708143/focus-on-input-field-and-orientation-change-messes-up-zoom-level-on-ios-6-safari) but link is for App, and not the site.

I have following meta tag (please note that zooming is purposely disabled - not my call, client's request :D)

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,initial-scale=1.0">
```

With zooming disabled and max-scale set to 1.0, orientation change works fine when you are just browsing the site. However, when you focus on input and change orientation, it starts to add some weird stuff on page.

When changing from:
portrait to landscape - iPad adds some black block at bottom of the page.
landscape to portrait - width of page gets wider. I inspected the element using mac and that whatever the space added is outside of html and shows up even with `overflow: hidden;` on both html and body tag.

Same issue happens on sign-in page of google - orientation change works perfectly fine when not focused on input fields, but when you focus on either email or password field and change orientation, iPad zooms in for some reason (you have to focus from portrait then once keyboard is visible, change orientation to landscape, it zooms in).

Luckily for Google, user is able to zoom-in and out but for me there's requirement from client that zooms has to be disabled.

Anyone have any workaround about this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this issue appears when page height is not set or set to 100%. I just set min height for page container.